# Polling SQS using dropwizard

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dropwizard, amazon-sqs

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I want to make a dropwizard client that polls Amazon SQS.
Whenever a message is found in the queue, it is processed and stored.

Some information about the processed messages will be available through an API.

**Why I chose Dropwizard:**

Seemed like a good choice to make a REST client. I need to have metrics, DB connections and integrate with some Java services.

**What I need help with:**

It is not very clear how and where the SQS polling will fit in a typical dropwizard application.
Should it be a managed resource? Or a console reporter [console-reporter](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.0.0/getting-started.html#console-reporter)? Or something else.

Comment: What kind of polling do you need? At fixed interval or as long as messages are available in the queue?

Comment: I had to implement a somewhat "smart" polling (long polling + back-off strategies + message blocking). These are implementation level details for my use case though. The first answer was a good enough pointer in the right direction :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractScheduledService` to create a consumer thread and add it to the dropwizard's environment lifecycle as `ManagedTask`. Following is the pseudocode -

```
public class YourSQSConsumer extends AbstractScheduledService {
  @Override
  protected void startUp() {
    // may be print something
  }

  @Override
  protected void shutDown() {
    // may be print something
  }

  @Override
  protected void runOneIteration() {
    // code to poll on SQS 
  }

  @Override
  protected Scheduler scheduler() {
     return newFixedRateSchedule(5, 1, SECONDS);
  }
}
```

In `Main` do this -

```
YourSQSConsumer consumer = new YourSQSConsumer();
Managed managedTask = new ManagedTask(consumer);
environment.lifecycle().manage(managedTask);
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to [RishikeshDhokare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52096642/2141670), one can also go ahead with the following code which does not need to include additional jar as a dependency in your project to keep the uber jar as much lightweight as possible.

```
public class SQSPoller implements Managed, Runnable {

    private ScheduledExecutorService mainRunner;

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        mainRunner = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
        mainRunner.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // poll SQS here
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        mainRunner.shutdown();
    }
}
```

And in the run() of your Application class, you can register the above class as follows.

```
environment.lifecycle().manage(new SQSPoller());
```

You can use either [scheduleWithFixedDelay()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) or [scheduleAtFixedRate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) depending upon your use case.